# A property of a reflexive space regarding distance between a point on the unit circle and a proper closed subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $Y$ be a proper closed subspace of a normed linear space $X$. Show that there exists $x\in S_{X}$ satisfying $d(x,Y)=1$, if either $X$ is reflexive or $Y$ is finite dimensional.(Here, $S_{X}$ is the unit circle.).

Now 
I have done the problem assuming that $Y$ is finite dimensional subspace,by imitating the proof of Riesz lemma and by using Bolzano-Weierstrass' theorem, which holds in finite dimensional case.

But I am stuck at the case when $X$ is reflexive. I tried to use the following idea. Since $X$ is reflexive, any linear functional assumes its norm on $S_{X}$.
Now, I was trying somehow to produce a linear functional whose norm is 1 and the point on $S_{X}$ where it assumes the norm , say $x_{0}$, we can have $f(x_{0})=d(x_{0}, Y)$.

I know that there is a consequence of Hahn-Banach theorem, which states that if $Y$ is a proper closed subspace of a normed linear space $X$, and $x\in X-Y$, then there exists a linear functional $f\in X^{*}$, such that $||f||=1, f(x)=d(x,Y), f(y)=0 \forall y\in Y$. But this doesn't seem to help!

I want to know whether this approach is at all valid! Any other ideas are also welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $Y$ is a closed proper subspace you have an $f\in X^*$ so that $f\lvert_Y = 0$ but $f\neq0$. Via Hahn Banach you can extend the linear functional $x':\mathrm{span}(f)\to\Bbb C$, $\lambda\,f\mapsto \lambda\|f\|$ to a map $x:X^*\to\Bbb C$ so that $\|x\|=\|x'\|=1$. Since $X$ is reflexive you can identify this functional, which is an element of $X^{**}$, with an element of $X$.

Now $d(x,Y)=\inf_{y\in Y}\|x-y\|≤1$, but on the other hand if $y\in Y$ you have $(x-y)(f)=\|f\|$. It follows
$$\|x-y\|=\sup_{\xi \in X^*}\frac{|(x-y)(\xi)|}{\|\xi\|}≥1$$
for any $y\in Y$ and then $d(x,Y)≥1$.

Comment: How is annihilator $Y^{*}$ of Y defined?

Comment: Those functionals that are zero when restricted to $Y$. $Y^*$ may not be the best notation.

Comment: Meaning that elements of $X^{*}$, that is, linear functionals on X which are 0 on $Y$?

Comment: So, by your notation is $Y^{*} \subset X^{*}$

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: I don't understand your notations and way of writing. Can you make it clear., Can you write from where to where you are defining the maps using HBT, and with what conditions?

Comment: I have edited the answer, is it more clear now?

Comment: Thanks a lot..  It is now clear!